# Must $1+X$ be irreducible in any polynomial ring $R[X]$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a multiplicative id. The question reads:

> Let $r$ be an element of a ring $R$. Show that, in the polynomial ring $R[X]$, the polynomial $1+rX$ is a unit
>   if and only if $r$ is nilpotent. Is it possible for the polynomial $1 + X$ to be a product of two non-units?

I've done the first part, it wasn't too bad. But I'm quite stuck with the second, and any hints or pointers would be appreciated. Am I looking for a proof or counterexample? What kind of thing should I be looking at? Etc.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make the question clearer?

Comment: You look for a proof for awhile, then look for a counterexample for awhile, etc.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes I didn't just post without trying... I've been at this for about an hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Is there any ring where it is possible to write $1 + X = (1+aX)(1+bX)$?

Comment: That's possible (without making $(1+aX)$ or $(1+bX)$ units) if and only if $a+b=1, ab=0$ which implies $b(1-b)=0$ or equivalently $b=b^2$ which means we are not in an integral domain... Does $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ with $b=3+\mathbb{Z},a=4+\mathbb{Z}$ work? (P.S. Thanks a lot :))

Comment: @Shakespeare That's exactly what I had in mind.  You can use the first part to conclude that these factors are not units.

Comment: @Sha Indeed, $\ (1+ax)(1+(1\!-\!a)x)\, =\, 1+x\ $ in $\ \Bbb Z/a(a\!-\!1)\ \ $