# Showing polynomial is not necessarily irreducible in a ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am starting a course on rings and am trying to get a feel of things. I've been asked whether $1+X$ can be written as the product of two non-units in $R[X]$ for some commutative ring $R$.

I thought of taking $R=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and:
$$(1+X)(1+X)=\underbrace{X(X+1)}_{\text{even}}+X+1=1+X$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The product $(1+X)(1+X)$ is $1+X^2$  but not $1+X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct. The problem is that you seem to confuse a polynomial, which is a formal linear combination of powers of a variable $X$, with the associated polynomial function $R\to R$. This is not much of a problem in $\mathbb{R}$ or other infinite fields and rings, but in a finite ring it is not true that a polynomial which is zero on every value of $X$ has to be zero.

For a correct example for your question, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147572/must-1x-be-irreducible-in-any-polynomial-ring-rx?rq=1).